# How to make subscript size bigger globally and locally

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, subscripts

Hello StackExchangers.

I need to make subscripts in math mode greater in two separate ways: in a whole document; locally within a paragraph or a table.

I have tried modifying the `\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{9}{9}` in the preamble, but this has no effect. I applied `\usepackage{fix-cm}`.

Can anyone crack this?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  There's not enough information here to provide any reliable answer.  Please add a brief, compilable example file, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, demonstrating the problem you report.  Font sizes are set in a document class, but may be modified by a loaded package.  Without knowing what you have done, any answer would be only a guess.

Comment: Interestingly, subscripts don't use \scriptsize.

Comment: the command you show will affect the math sizes if the text size is 12pt and if no other package has re-issued that with different values, but impossible to say if either of those things is true with the information you have provided.

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- `\scriptsize` is a text font size.  The math equivalent is `\scriptstyle`, and that is what should be set by `\DeclareMathSizes`.